# Tabular column in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to use `UITableview` in iPhone to show data in tabular format, just like Excel which has many columns that doesn't fit in 320px width? It has almost 15 columns and 15 rows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not like Grid view.. A proper tabular column.

Comment: Yes there is, use UICollectionView

Comment: Hmm... I'd say that you can probably change the design to make the data easier to display. Just because it is spreadsheet format at the moment doesn't necessarily mean it has to be in spreadsheet format on the phone.

Comment: @Fr33KiLL Add textbox in scrollview and set its contentsize more than 320 for width.

Comment: @Fogmeister - The data is not in excel format, but the client needs it show them in excel format.

Comment: @Fr33KiLL, you may need to develop one for yourself, I have just done something similar a few days ago, with a locked first column and row (everything else scrollable). it took about 3 hours coding, thus it is not a big deal.

Comment: @holex, How did you do it..? Any hint, so that I will have a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can customize you tableview using custom cell and a customized scrollable header view for table section.

Try adding a scrollview in your Custom cell and manage scrolling of the cell depending upon the header view scrolling through scrollview delegates.

Instead using the UICollectionView would be an better option.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UICollectionView`. Check [the link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-1)